# Can a class implementing multiple interfaces (shown below) cause errors when b.y() is called?

Tags: java, oop, interface

Suppose class A implements interfaces B and C.

Many books conventionally use one of the following formats:

```
B b = new A();
```

OR

```
C c = new A();
```

Suppose method `x` is specified in interface `B` and method `y` is specified in interface `C`.

**Question :**

Can the object `b` call method `y` specified in interface `C` by using the following syntax ?

```
b.y();
```

Could you please give an answer in terms of a specific java example (e.g. `List` interface and `ArrayLists`, `LinkedLists`).

Comment: Couldn't you just try it?

Comment: You must cast the reference to the type to be referenced.  (Or simply cast it to the class it is, which implements both interfaces.)

Comment: (And "give an answer in terms of a specific java example" sounds an awful lot like a homework question.  Do your own homework.)

Comment: No, you cannot call method `Y` using `b.X()`.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. This is definitely not for homework -- it was for better understanding. I'm on a computer with heavy restrictions -- can't install additional software.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch -- Y is a method; not an interface.

Comment: @QNZ9WTX9W9 Your question is hard to follow. But if interface B extends interface C (which includes method Y), then a class implementing interface B must also include method Y.

Comment: *"Can a class implementing multiple interfaces cause errors described below?"* - What errors?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch -- yes the way I had written it was confusing. I've now fixed it. I meant to write b.y(); Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

At compile time, method invocations are bound based on the type of the expression (or value) they are invoked on. This is known as a compile time type or static type.

If that type (or its super types) contains an accessible method of that name which satisfies the argument(s) provided, then compilation will pass for that invocation. If no such method exists, compilation will fail.

Consider that `LinkedList` implements both `List` and `Deque`.

Comment: So, are you suggesting that b.X(); will cause a compile time error?

Comment: @QNZ9WTX9W9 _If that type (or its super types) contains an accessible method of that name which satisfies the argument(s) provided, then compilation will pass for that invocation. If no such method exists, compilation will fail._

Comment: @QNZ9WTX9W9 `X()` is declared in `B`, so invoking it on an expression of type `B` is fine, assuming here that `b` is of type `B`.

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1: Can the object 'b' call method `y` specified in interface `C` by using the following syntax?
>
> ```
>    b.x();
> ```

No it can't.

`b.y()` calls a method whose name is `y`.

Now I suppose that you could code some class that implements `B` and `C` so that it's implementation of method `y()` calls `y()`.  But the `b.y()` call will always start by calling a `y()` method.

> Question 2: Can the object 'b' call method `y` specified in interface `C` by using the following syntax?
>
> ```
>    b.y();
> ```

No it can't.

The static type of `b` is `B`, and `B` does define a method called `y`.  This will give you a compilation error saying that there is no `y()` method in `B`.

---

> Question 3: So, are you suggesting that b.x(); will cause a compile time error?

No.  `b` has a static type `B`, and `B` defines the method `x()`.  Therefore the call is valid.

Comment: Thank you @Stephen C. I've edited the question according to your comments. I also made an important change. Will it work for b.y()?